# error: ‘class btMatrix3x3’ has no member named ‘getRPY’ when building tf

Tags: ros, bullet, beaglebone, build, rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello -- I'm trying to build `tf` from source on a beagle. I built the `fuerte-ros-base.rosinstall` and that all installed properly. I downloaded `tf` using:

```
roslocate info tf | rosws merge -
rosws update
```

I also installed `bullet` using

```
roslocate info bullet | rosws merge -
rosws update
```

after sorting out all my other dependencies I ran

```
rosmake geometry
```

and now I am getting errors:

```
  /home/ubuntu/ros/geometry/tf/include/tf/transform_datatypes.h: In function ‘double tf::getYaw(const Quaternion&)’:
  /home/ubuntu/ros/geometry/tf/include/tf/transform_datatypes.h:140:21: error: ‘class btMatrix3x3’ has no member named ‘getRPY’
  /home/ubuntu/ros/geometry/tf/include/tf/transform_datatypes.h: In function ‘tf::Quaternion tf::createQuaternionFromRPY(double, double, double)’:
  /home/ubuntu/ros/geometry/tf/include/tf/transform_datatypes.h:159:5: error: ‘tf::Quaternion’ has no member named ‘setRPY’
  /home/ubuntu/ros/geometry/tf/include/tf/transform_datatypes.h: In function ‘tf::Quaternion tf::createQuaternionFromYaw(double)’:
  /home/ubuntu/ros/geometry/tf/include/tf/transform_datatypes.h:169:5: error: ‘tf::Quaternion’ has no member named ‘setRPY’
  /home/ubuntu/ros/geometry/tf/include/tf/transform_datatypes.h: In function ‘geometry_msgs::Quaternion tf::createQuaternionMsgFromYaw(double)’:
  /home/ubuntu/ros/geometry/tf/include/tf/transform_datatypes.h:179:5: error: ‘tf::Quaternion’ has no member named ‘setRPY’
  /home/ubuntu/ros/geometry/tf/include/tf/transform_datatypes.h: In function ‘tf::Quaternion tf::createIdentityQuaternion()’:
  /home/ubuntu/ros/geometry/tf/include/tf/transform_datatypes.h:203:5: error: ‘tf::Quaternion’ has no member named ‘setRPY’
```

I saw this old message on ros-users which seemed relevant:

http://code.ros.org/lurker/message/20091009.014115.55a2c1bd.ca.html

but that was ages ago, and it claims that this problem was fixed. (I tried deleting bullet/build as recommended in that email just in case, but that didn't resolve anything)

I'm guessing it has something to do with a version mismatch between the geometry stack and the bullet stack that I have picked up. `roslocate` gave me the `tf_rework` branch of `geometry` and the `default` branch of `bullet`.

Which branches should I use for use with `fuerte`?

### Thanks

UPDATE: I tried using the `tf_rework` branch of `bullet` and I received this error when building:

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
GLUT_INCLUDE_DIR (ADVANCED)
   used as include directory in directory /home/ubuntu/ros/bullet/bullet/build/bullet_svn
```

[...]

```
GLUT_glut_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)
    linked by target "OpenGLSupport" in directory /home/ubuntu/ros/bullet/bullet/build/bullet_svn/Demos/OpenGL
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48328/error:-%E2%80%98class-btmatrix3x3%E2%80%99-has-no-member-named-%E2%80%98getrpy%E2%80%99-when-building-tf/) by [sameer](https://answers.ros.org/users/3158/sameer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 118 on 2012-11-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I set the branch in `geometry` to `fuerte_devel` and the branch in `bullet` to `default` and now it compiles nicely.

---

Originally posted by [sameer](https://answers.ros.org/users/3158/sameer/) with karma: 118 on 2012-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nemesis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4134/nemesis/) on 2013-03-14**:
@sameer - I am trying to add a bit of my code to the source code of a pre-built package so that I can get R,P,Y values for a particular bot. The issue is I tried "making" the file after I put in the same code using getRPY but it shows me the same error. Could you please help me with this?